# TypeError: 'value' must be an instance of str or bytes, not a float

Tags: python, dataframe, data-science, scatter-plot

I'm trying to visualize two column using scatter plot but I keep got the same error and I've been tried to change the data type but it didn't work. Here my code.

```
fig, ax= plt.subplots(figsize=(4,6))

# Title & subtitle
fig.text(0.097,1,'land area and average volume of', fontfamily='serif',fontsize=15, fontweight='bold')
# Ax spines

ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(True)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('lightgray')

# Grid
ax.set_axisbelow(True)
ax.yaxis.grid(color='lightgray', linestyle='-')
# Plot
plt.scatter(x = 'land area(m2)' , y= 'average_volume(m3)',
            data = data ,color='#114a31',s = 25, alpha= 0.8)
# Tick control
plt.yticks(fontsize=10, fontfamily='serif' ,fontweight='light')
plt.xticks(fontsize=10, fontfamily='serif' ,fontweight='light' ,rotation=90)

# Label control
ax.set_ylabel('wilayah',fontfamily='serif' ,fontsize=12)
ax.set_xlabel('jenis_tps' ,fontfamily='serif' ,fontsize=12)

ax.set_ylim(0, 100)
plt.axhline(y = 0, color= 'black', linewidth = 1.3, alpha= .7)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Are you running it line by line or alltogether? What i want to know is which line is giving you this error.

Comment: Can you also give an example of data?

Comment: Since the x and y strings are indexes into the data variable, the way you have constructed data is probably quite key (ie does data have these exact indices?)

Comment: Is `data` a pandas dataframe? I'm guesing this is where your error is coming from. Your code works fine for me with a dataframe that has two columns: 'land area(m2)' and 'average_volume(m3)'. Without seeing the dataframe, I can't really say anythign else.

Answer (score 0):

```
plt.scatter(x = 'land area(m2)' , y= 'average_volume(m3)',
```

x and y need to be arrays containing the X and Y values respectively, or else see my edit, the data needs to be a `pandas.DataFrame` with the column names given to x and y.  Both examples given below work with your code, I therefore assume there is an error in how your `data` looks. Example of required data format given below.
Example:

```
plt.scatter(x = range(10), y=range(10,110, 10) ,color='#114a31',s = 25, alpha= 0.8)
```

[image: Plot of example data]

**EDIT:**

As I was made aware of by the comments, x and y can be strings, if data is a dataframe with column names being the string given in x and y

```
data = pd.DataFrame()
data["X"] = [i for i in range(10)]
data["Y"] = [i for i in range(10,110,10)]
# Plot
plt.scatter(x = "X", y="Y", data=data ,color='#114a31',s = 25, alpha= 0.8)
```

```
data
Out[127]: 
   X    Y
0  0   10
1  1   20
2  2   30
3  3   40
4  4   50
5  5   60
6  6   70
7  7   80
8  8   90
9  9  100
```

Comment: There is support for `x` and `y` being keys to the data: See the [release notes](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_1.5.html#working-with-labeled-data-like-pandas-dataframes)

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html?highlight=scatter#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter

"Note: In addition to the above described arguments, this function can take a data keyword argument. If such a data argument is given, the following arguments can also be string s, which is interpreted as data[s] (unless this raises an exception): x, y, s, linewidths, edgecolors, c, facecolor, facecolors, color."

Objects passed as data must support item access (data[s]) and membership test (s in data)

Comment: Thanks guys, I didn't know that. I will update the answer to the possibility, however, his code works perfectly fine as above, therefore his problem lies in the data definition. I will wait for his response on how data looks for the update